# How to roll up events into metadata from original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like

```
Name,Report_ID,Amount,Flag,Actions
Fizz,123,5,,A
Fizz,123,10,Y,A
Buzz,456,10,,B
Buzz,456,40,,C
Buzz,456,70,,D
Bazz,678,100,Y,F
```

From these individual operations, i'd like to create a new dataframe that captures various statistics / meta name. Mostly summations and counts of items / counts of unique entries. I'd like the output of the dataframe to look like the following:

```
Report_ID,Number of Flags,Number of Entries, Total,Unique Actions
123,1,2,15,1
456,0,3,120,3
678,1,1,100,1
```

I've tried using `groupby`, but I cannot merge all of the individual groupby objects back together correctly. So far I've tried

```
totals = raw_data.groupby('Report_ID')['Amount'].sum()
event_count = raw_data.groupby('Report_ID').size()
num_actions = raw_data.groupby('Report_ID').Actions.nunique()

output = pd.concat([totals,event_count,num_actions])
```

When I try this i get `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg` on the `groupby`

```
f = dict(Flag=['count', 'size'], Amount='sum', Actions='nunique')
df.groupby('Report_ID').agg(f)

           Flag      Amount Actions
          count size    sum nunique
Report_ID                          
123           1    2     15       1
456           0    3    120       3
678           1    1    100       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `axis=1` when concatenating:

```
event_count.name = 'Event Count'  # Name the Series, as you did not group on one.
>>> pd.concat([totals, event_count, num_actions], axis=1)

           Amount  Event Count  Actions
Report_ID                              
123            15            2        1
456           120            3        3
678           100            1        1
```